# Android : show a splash with animation

Tags: android, android-animation, splash-screen

In my activity, when a user action succeeds i want to show a circle that animate out from center to outside as a splash color and then disappears showing the content as before. How can i achieve this splash animation

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at this library https://github.com/hendraanggrian/reveallayout

Comment: The link you provided was pretty exact as per question but would help better if you have posted few parts of it in your answer.